# How To Change Custom Path of Gradle in Intelij Idea

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea

(1) I have changed the .gradle path to the custom directory from the home directory.

`OJDBC` jar file has been added into my maven localrepository with the following command

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=G:\Software\ojdbc\ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.4 -Dpackaging=jar
```

when I enable `mavenLocal()` in `build.gradle` to inject the jar from maven local repo then the following error has occurred.

```
 Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.4.
```

`mavenLocal()` is used localRepository path which is defined in the `settings.xml`.

**settings.xml**

```
  <localRepository>D:/Build Tools/.m2/repository</localRepository>
```

in my case, it doesn't work. But when I use the default build tool path(home directory) for `maven` and `Gradle` then it works.

(2) When I open a new project with IntelliJ Idea then each and every time I have to override maven local repository because my maven repo not located in the default path. If there is any way to start an IntelliJ idea with a custom location without using the default one?

Comment: (1) Does it work from command line outside IDE? (2) You could change defaults via "File | New Project Settings | Settings/Preferences for new projects".

Comment: (1) I  didn't check with CMD but checked with eclipse but the problem is the same. it didn't work

Comment: (2) yes. I have to change the default each and every time when to open the new project. some time IDE uses the default path before made the configuration

Comment: (2) Have you tried to change defaults via "File | New Project Settings | Settings/Preferences for new projects" ?

Comment: of course. I tried and changed it. I want to override my custom location permanently then don't need to change each and every time when creating a new project with IntelliJ Idea

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-245365

Comment: Thanks, you save my time

Answer (score 0):

I have solved (1) with the following way

if I use custom location of maven repo then I can replace `mavenLocal()` with `maven{}`

```
repositories {
    //mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url '/path/to/your/repository'
    }
}
```